# NGINX service failure in Dockers on limiting memory and CPU usage

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have one Master and 5 worker nodes, I am using the following command while deploying the nginx service.

It fails-

```
docker service create --name foo -p 32799:80 -p 32800:443  nginx --limit-cpu 0.5 --limit-memory 512M
```

On the other hand this works-

```
docker service create --name foo -p 32799:80 -p 32800:443  nginx
```

Please let me know how do I reduce my CPU to 1 core and limit memory to 512M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your command to the following and try again:

```
docker service create --limit-cpu 0.5 --limit-memory 512M --name foo -p 32799:80 -p 32800:443  nginx
```

Anything following the `image name` is treated as `COMMAND` and parameters.